# JavaFx: Check if Username and Password in Registration is matched with Login

Tags: javafx

I want to check if usernames and passwords in Regisration.java are matched with usernames and passwords in Login.java. For example, if I type in "Ali" as username, and "123" as password in Registration.java and saved it, which I have already done. Then, when I go to Login.java and type in for example "Ross" as username and "1010" as password in Login.java, it will print "Username or Password is wrong"

Users.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author ammar
 */
public class Users {
    public static ArrayList<String> usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> passwords = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public void addusers(String u, String p){
        usernames.add(u);
        passwords.add(p);
    }
    public  ArrayList getUserNames()
    {
        return usernames;
    }
    public ArrayList getPasswords()
    {
        return passwords;
    }
    
    
}
```

Login.java

```
package javaapplication6;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author ammar
 */
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label Titlelbl;
    @FXML
    private Label UserNamelbl;
    @FXML
    private Label Passwordlbl;
    @FXML
    private Button Registerbtn;
    @FXML
    private Button Loginbtn;
    @FXML
    private Label Forgetbtn;
    private Label Outputlbl;
    @FXML
    private TextField UserNametxt;
    @FXML
    private TextField Passwordtxt;
    @FXML
    private Label Outputlbl1;
    @FXML
    private Label Outputlbl2;
    @FXML
    private ImageView Img;
    @FXML
    private Button Viewbtn;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
         Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/javaapplication6/icons/uqu.png"));
        
        Img.setImage(image);
    }

    @FXML
    private void Login(ActionEvent event) {
        
       
        
        var valid = true;

        // Validate the username field
        if (UserNametxt.getText().isEmpty() ) {
            valid = false;
            Outputlbl1.setText("Please Enter User Name ");
            
        } else if (UserNametxt.getText().equals("Ali")) {
            Outputlbl1.setText("Welcome");
            
        } else {
            Outputlbl1.setText("In");
        }
       

        if (Passwordtxt.getText().isEmpty()) {

            valid = false;
            Outputlbl2.setText("Please Enter Password");
           
        
            
        } else {
            Outputlbl2.setText("");
        }
        

    }

    @FXML
    private void Registerbtn(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SecondWindow.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Cant load new window");
        }
    }
    
    @FXML
    private void view(ActionEvent event) {
        Users u = new Users();
        ArrayList<String> uname = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> pass = new ArrayList<String>();
        uname = u.getUserNames();
        pass = u.getPasswords();
        System.out.println("The user Names-"+uname);
    }



   
}
```

Registration.java (I named it SecondWindowController.java):

```
package javaapplication6;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author ammar
 */
public class SecondWindowController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button Backbtn;
    @FXML
    private Button Savebtn;
    @FXML
    private TextField UserNameReg;
    @FXML
    private TextField PasswordReg;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

    @FXML
    private void back(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
            stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void save(ActionEvent event) {
       Users user = new Users();
       user.addusers(UserNameReg.getText(), PasswordReg.getText());
    }

    
    
}
```

FXMain:

```
package javaapplication6;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author ammar
 */
public class FXMain extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/javaapplication6/Login.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("UQU");

        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Few points. 
1) The current approach you use is an in memory storage for usernames and passwords. This means every time you run the application, your store of usernames and passwords are cleared. Try persisting the data in a db say like sqlite
2)
`} else {Outputlbl2.setText(""); }`

Here, when the password is not empty, you actually do nothing with it. 

If you want to proceed with the in memory storage, I'll recommend a HashMap<String, String> to store each username with it's corresponding password.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SimpleLoginSQLiteFx

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SimpleLoginTextFileFx